# Rails route with arbitrary number of slashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a custom route based on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints that checks for redirects based on a url entered.

For instance /site may redirect to /mysite

Here is the code:

```
class RedirectCheck
  def initialize
    @redirects = Redirect.all_from_paths
  end

  def matches?(request)
    @redirects.include?(request[:path])
  end
end

MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  get ":path" => 'redirects#show', constraints: RedirectCheck.new
end
```

Redirect.all_from_paths basically is a model method that returns an array of all the accepted routes and then 'redirects#show' does the actual redirect.

Now my problem is that the route..

```
get ":path" => 'redirects#show', constraints: RedirectCheck.new
```

..will not accept paths with slashes in them

So for example I can't add a path like /go/some/where my redirect route will not recognize it

How do I change this line so it will accept any path with any number of slashes and passes it as params[:path] to 'redirects#show'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is:

```
get "*path", to: 'redirects#show', constraints: RedirectCheck.new
```

And there are many other examples at the [Rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing-and-wildcard-segments).

Comment: This is great, but it'd be even better if you could add a little more detail - don't forget that total noobs will be on this site hoping to understand why this works. Perhaps explain the properties of the `*` for them :)

Comment: Okay now I feel dumb for not trying that :)